# How I can invokes the myC1delegate inside myProc1?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Definition:

```
delegate void myC1(string mystring);
```

Method:

```
public static void myProc1 (myC1 method, string mystring);
```

How I can invokes the myC1delegate inside myProc1?

Comment: Expecting answer one of the following 
   a. (*method)(mystring);
   b. method.mystring;
   c. (*method):mystring;
   d. this->(*method)(mystring);
e. method (mystring);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate is the equivalent of function pointer in C/C++ you have to assign the method you want to  invoke and it should respect the delegate signature

```
  public class Program
    {
       public  delegate void myC1(string myStr); 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myC1 meth = new Program().MethodToInvoke;  
             myProc1(meth,"test invoke");                             
        }                  
        public void MethodToInvoke( string str )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");                    
        }

        public static void myProc1(myC1 method, string mystring)    
        {                
            method(mystring);  
            //this will print test                     
        }    
    }
```

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/index)

*`A delegate is a type that represents references to methods with a particular parameter list and return type. When you instantiate a delegate, you can associate its instance with any method with a compatible signature and return type. You can invoke (or call) the method through the delegate instance.`*